# AWS - Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool in swift.

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I have custom UI for Signup and Singing so not using AWSAuthUI

I was able to successfully setup Signup by following the documentation and am able to see confirm users in the user pool.

I am facing issue in DynamoDB Access (Authentication issue)

Bellow is the code is am using for Login

```
@IBAction func btn_login(_ sender: UIButton) {
    ActivityIndicator.start()
    if(txt_soul_id.text != "" && txt_pwd.text != ""){

        let emailTextField = txt_soul_id.text!
        let passwordTextField = txt_pwd.text!

        let len = passwordTextField.count
        if(len > 7){
            if(Validations.isValidPassword(password: passwordTextField)){
                let mypool = configuration.pool?.getUser(emailTextField)

                mypool?.getSession(emailTextField, password: passwordTextField, validationData: nil).continueWith(block: { (task) in
                    if(task.error != nil){
                        ActivityIndicator.stop()
                        Alerts.normal_display(msg_title: "", msg_desc: (task.error?._userInfo!["message"])!, action_title: "OK", myVC: self)
                    }else{
                        ActivityIndicator.stop()
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditProfileVC_sid") as! EditProfileVC
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                        }
                    }
                    return nil
                })
            }else{
                ActivityIndicator.stop()
                Alerts.normal_display(msg_title: "", msg_desc: "Password must require number, special character, uppercase and lowercase letter.", action_title: "Ok", myVC: self)
            }
        }else{
            ActivityIndicator.stop()
            Alerts.normal_display(msg_title: "Minimum 8 Character", msg_desc: "Your password must be at least 8 characters", action_title: "Ok", myVC: self)
        }
    }else{
        ActivityIndicator.stop()
        Alerts.normal_display(msg_title: "Required", msg_desc: "Username and password required", action_title: "OK", myVC: self)
    }
}
```

Upon successful login I am trying to save into the dynamodb model I have created

```
@IBAction func save_profile(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
    // Create data object using data models you downloaded from Mobile Hub
    let userItem: User = User()
    var stype : [String]? = nil
    stype?.append("soltype1")
     userItem._userId = AWSIdentityManager.default().identityId
    //userItem._soultypes = stype
    userItem._about = "About Me"
    userItem._bday = "19-19-1991"
    userItem._culture = "Jain"
    userItem._email = "abc@gmail.com"
    userItem._mobile = 1234567890
    userItem._mobilePrefix = "+32"
    userItem._soulid = "mysid"


    //Save a new item
    dynamoDbObjectMapper.save(userItem, completionHandler: {
        (error: Error?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Amazon DynamoDB Save Error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        print("An item was saved.")
    })
}
```

**userItem._userId is nil**

Gives error nil for identityId along with Amazon DynamoDB Save Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.}